# Azure bug when scaling only ONE website (not all of them)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I had one **free** website in Azure, lets call it "website1".

Then I created **another free website** (lets call it "website2"), using these settings:

[image: Settings]

As you can see, I choose: "Create **new** web hosting plan", so "website2" should be totally unlinked with "website1". They only information they share is the subscription (credit card)

Then, after "website 2" being created, I wanted to scale "website 2" from "Free" to "Shared".

But now they are at the same "web hosting plan", and before I told Azure that they should be different!

[image: Argh 1]

[image: Argh 2]

So.. my question is:
I want to scale one of them to "Shared" and the other to remain "Free". How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well... this worked: (1) Delete "website 2", (2) Scale up "website1" to "basic", (3) Create "website 2" as a new "web hosting plan", (4) Now one is free and the other "basic", (5) Scale down "website 1" to free, (6) Now one is free and the other shared. THANKS AZURE

Answer (score 0):

Correct, in the current portal you can't change them independently.

You can change them via the API or use the preview portal.

Read about it at:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

Or just visit the preview portal at:
http://portal.azure.com and make the change there.